# Are things embedded in a "bed"?

Tags: meaning

Consider:

> "The identity process is culturally embedded."

Is the following then possible?

> "Cosmopolitanism constitutes the cultural **bed** of this identity process."

Comment: I've never heard "bed" used in this sense. The closest I can think of which can be used figuratively is "cradle", but I'm not certain it expresses what you want to say. The sentence you give with "bed" has a meaning unclear to me.

Comment: I think it works; in the sense of a flowerbed, or bedrock.

Comment: ... or "bedded in"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the formulation you are using. It's a rather artistic way for expressing something like

> Cosmopolitanism is the cultural foundation of this identity process.

The question is whether being artistic is ok in the context of your writing. I wouldn't use it in science though.

Answer (score 3):

No. It would probably be understood, but it is not a standard usage, and many readers would question why you are using such an unusual metaphor. "Matrix" or "substrate" are better words.

Comment: and I am questioning it myself! :)